# php mail log is not created

Tags: php, email, logging

Heey 
i want to log outgoing mails they was sent via php.

Now i have found this option:
mail.add_x_header -> http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Also i have put this lines in my php.ini:

```
mail.add_x_header = On 
mail.log = /var/log/phpMail.log
```

Here my ini files:
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/opt/keyhelp/php/7.0/etc/php.ini

afther that i have restart the apache and the php-fpm.

But if i send a mail, the server dont create the log.

Does anyone have any idea what i could test.

Comment: Check for Write permission

Comment: of what? the var/log?

Comment: Yes the log path as well as check if you properly pointed the log file from your virtual host settings or from the config file settings

Comment: looks ok, the ini and the var/log is owned by the root

Comment: check phpinfo() - did your changes reflect in it?

Comment: Not sure but try changing mail.add_x_header = On  TO mail.add_x_header = 1

Comment: Also the logs can be maintained when you send mail through PHP's mail() function

Comment: @Toly yes i can see the setiing in there:
mail.add_x_header On On
mail.log /var/log/phpMail.log /var/log/phpMail.log

Comment: @vanurag nope, unfortunately no success :(

Comment: @vanurag can you explain this comment: Also the logs can be maintained when you send mail through PHP's mail() function ? please

Comment: Well, usually apache is runned under www-data user, you say that the folder on this path belongs to root. Try changing the path of the log file to some file which can be accessed by your user (under which the web server is running). Possibly - see where other logs are stored and point to file in that folder.

Comment: @Toly path is now: /var/log/apache2/phpMail.log but no log there

Comment: Well, check if the file exists.. :) Sometimes there are problems with that as well.

Comment: Also, how do you send mail? Wrote a script and opening it in browser? Or launching via console ssh?

Comment: the log file dosnt exist but if i create an empty the server dosnt log anything too

Comment: i launch the script with mail() via browser (y)

Comment: if i launch it per cli i have no success too

Comment: You know this merely logs `mail()` function calls anyway, not any headers or mail body. Also just use `/tmp/mail.log` for testing. Also `chmod a+rw` it.

Comment: @mario thx, in /tmp it work, but why not in /var/log/apache2 ? and thank you for the hint, but i only need some information about outgoing mails, e.g. if some body spams with a script

Comment: You've been told to look up the `user=` which FPM runs with. And make the log file owned by that user. Then you may use `/var/log/…`

Comment: hm, but the process is owned by root: 
6509    root        root           1       0.00s      0.00s        0K         0K        0K        0K     --      -    S         2      0%    php-fpm7.0

Comment: PHP-FPM never runs as root, except for the dispatcher process.

Comment: thats the atop output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to check log file permissions:

- `ls -l /var/log/phpMail.log`
- `egrep 'user\s*=' /etc/php/*/fpm/pool.d/*.conf`

And set owner or permission:

- `chown fpm-user /var/log/phpMail.log`
- or `chmod a+rw /var/log/phpMail.log`